# PhoneGap/jQuery Mobile on Android gets pushed down

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm just starting to use Phone Gap with jQuery Mobile so I don't quite know how to debug and what sort of debugging tools are available on the emulators.

The header title bar gets pushed down a bit on the Android emulator (AVD_for_Nexus_7_by_Google).  However, everything looks fine on the iOS simulator and web browsers.

Any ideas what might be happening or what I might try to debug this?

Here's the code:

```
  <!-- Start of index page -->
  <div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content"> 
      <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="" data-transition="slide">hihi</a>
          <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="" data-transition="slide">hihi1</a>
              <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
                <li>examplea</li> 
                <li>exampleb</li> 
                <li>exampleb</li> 
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="" data-transition="slide">hihi2</a>
              <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
                <li>example2</li> 
                <li>example2</li> 
                <li>example2</li> 
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="" data-transition="slide">hihi3</a>
              <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
                <li>example3</li> 
                <li>example3</li> 
                <li>example3</li> 
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /page -->
```

Here's an image of what I'm seeing:
[image]

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `margin-top:0` in your code.

Code is :-

```
.ui-shadow, .ui-btn-up-a, .ui-btn-hover-a, .ui-btn-down-a, .ui-body-b, .ui-btn-up-b, .ui-    btn-hover-b, .ui-btn-down-b, .ui-bar-c, .ui-body-c, .ui-btn-up-c, .ui-btn-hover-c, .ui-btn-down-c, .ui-bar-c, .ui-body-d, .ui-btn-up-d, .ui-btn-hover-d, .ui-btn-down-d, .ui-bar-d, .ui-body-e, .ui-btn-up-e, .ui-btn-hover-e, .ui-btn-down-e, .ui-bar-e, .ui-overlay-shadow, .ui-shadow, .ui-btn-active, .ui-body-a, .ui-bar-a {
    box-shadow: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Just add this to your CSS. Also remember PhoneGap is easy, just make sure you read the documentation properly.

Comment: Hi Aamir, sorry I forgot to add that I'm also using jQuery Mobile.  And it sounds like it's more of a jQuery Mobile issue since it's only the CSS that should be causing this weird behavior.  I've updated the question.  It just boggles my mind that everything looks fine on web browsers and iOS, but not on the Android emulator.  I tried your advice, but the behaviour is still showing up.  I'll try to do more CSS debugging as that's what it seems like you're suggesting would be the most likely issue.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi Aamir, sorry I was only able to briefly try it.  But it didn't work.  I'll try more CSS later, but for the moment I'm just concentrating on iOS.  If it worked on Webkit browsers but not the emulator...then it seems like there might be something else going on.  Thank you for taking the time to respond.  I'll post more later.  Take care!